# How to modify Google Earth Polygon Properties through Excel Workbook Data

Tags: gis, google-earth, kmz

I am trying to find out how to use an Excel file to alter or manipulate the fill properties (Color) of polygons that make up a .KMZ file being used in Google Earth.

Example: The KMZ file named “Districts” has 398 separate district polygons.  I use an excel workbook with a list of the same districts divided among the Provinces they belong to.  Each district has security incidents catalogued daily for a seven-day period. One column for the Polygon names and one column for the number of incidents.

What will it take to change the properties of the polygons to filled with fill colors in accordance to the Excel sheets’ data (numbers) for each district?

Example: 0-2 incidents = Green, 3-5 incidents = Yellow and >5 incidents = Red

I only want the districts that fall in these categories to have a fill and corresponding color.

Most of the GE forums are dead and I cannot use any third party software.

Answer (score 0):

I perform a similar task using a template **KML** file. I load the KML file into a string then iterate over the spreadsheet and replace the approiate color value token with the color I need at the monment. I use string searching to find what I need but you could use your own defined tokens in the template to be replaced.

```
add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Set AQI_Numbers = Sheets("AQI_Data").Range("AQI_Numbers")

   ' add color to region placemarks in KML model
For col = 1 To AQI_Numbers.Columns.Count
    Date_String = Format(AQI_Numbers.Item(-1, col), "YYYY_mm_dd")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(ModelPath3) & "\AQI_Regions_Model3.kml.txt", ForReading)
    msKML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    For row = 1 To AQI_Numbers.Rows.Count ' range on sheet
        s = AQI_Numbers.Item(row, 0) ' region name
        t = InStr(msKML, "<name>" & s & "</name>")
        ' replace next <color> value
        t = InStr(t, msKML, "<PolyStyle>")
        t = InStr(t, msKML, "<color>") + 7
        t2 = InStr(t, msKML, "</color>")
        Mid(msKML, t, t2 - t) = GetKMLColor(AQI_Numbers.Item(row, col))
    Next
    ' save this day's KML
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(ModelPath3) & "\AQI_II_Maps\AQI_" & Date_String & ".kml", ForWriting, True)
    ts.Write msKML
    ts.Close
Next
```